# How to use older compiler with CMake Integration of Visual Studio 2019

Tags: cmake, grpc, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to compile gRPC on Windows into a DLL that is compatible with our C++ application that has to be compiled with the Visual Studio 2015 toolset.

Through the Visual Studio 2019 Installer I installed VS2019 together with the old C++ toolset (not IDE) of Visual Studio 2015.

When I open the freshly cloned gRPC source folder in VS2019 its CMake Integration creates the following `CMakeSettings.json` with default values:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com//fwlink//?linkid=834763 for more information about this file.
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I specify in the `CMakeSettings.json` file the following `-A` and `-T` options that I could specify when using CMake on the command line or the CMake GUI?

[image: CMakeGUI]

Comment: Did you try adding these options to the `cmakeCommandArgs` entry? Maybe something like this? `"cmakeCommandArgs": "-A x64 -T v140",`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this with the help of user squarekittles:

- The `-T` argument goes into `cmakeCommandArgs`.
- The `-A` argument must not be specified or you get an error because it is specified twice. It will be set through either `generator` or `inheritEnvironments` (not sure which one).
- `generator` has to be set to `Visual Studio {installed IDE version}`, not `Ninja`
- Due to the `generator` change, `buildCommandArgs` must be changed from `-v` to `/v:{desired verbosity level, see msbuild doc}`

All of these settings can be changed from the UI. Example:
[image]
[image]